# Why does wordpress wpdb->prepare change % into random guid

Tags: wordpress

This started out as me trying to figure out how to get something to work and being baffled by the output I was getting.  When I was testing to make sure I wrote this question clearly, I stumbled upon the answer.  Now this question becomes WHY does it behave this way as it was extremely confusing to me and led me to believe the problem was completely different than what it was.

I needed to query a custom table in the wordpress database that I created.  I needed several columns and there might be multiple rows, so I used `$wpdb->get_results`.  However, I know it's very important to prevent against sql injection so it's highly recommended to use it in conjunction with `$wpdb->prepare`.  In all of the examples I've seen, there are several ways that seem to work for others, such as:

```
$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ADDRESS LIKE %%%s%%", $tableName, $address
));
```

or

```
$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ADDRESS LIKE %s", $tableName, '%' . $address . '%'
));
```

However, while I'm developing this I'm using a variable and printing to screen for debugging purposes, like:

```
$theQuery = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ADDRESS LIKE %s", $tableName, '%' . $address . '%'
);
printf(nl2br("theQuery: " . $theQuery . PHP_EOL));
```

When I view the results, I receive this:

```
theQuery: SELECT * FROM 'wp_table' WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '{38f7caa660e456637b3924006588169e1912b28c0a81d0a4ae0d77885704a425}11th ST{38f7caa660e456637b3924006588169e1912b28c0a81d0a4ae0d77885704a425}'
```

It seems like the `$wpdb->prepare` statement is causing % to be turned into GUIDs of some type.  Every time I refresh the page, the GUIDs change in value, so it's generating new GUIDs for the % symbol each time.  This is obviously part of the way it provides safety against sql injections, but since I did not know it would behave in this way and never saw that in the documentation, I thought that was my issue.  I tried so many combinations and it always failed to retrieve any results and I always thought it was because it was mis-behaving with those GUIDs.  I ended up finding that the ACTUAL problem was including the table name as a parameter in the prepare statement.  It causeS the query to have single quotes around the table name, causing a MySQL syntax error and no results are returned.

Why exactly does it generate those GUIDs and during testing is there a way to print them as % to the browser for debugging?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a change made in WordPress 4.8.3 to fix a MySQL injection vulnerability.  Here's some links with more information.

https://make.wordpress.org/security/2017/11/13/the-war-on-sqli-or-what-happened-in-4-8-2-and-4-8-3/

https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2017/10/disclosure-wordpress-wpdb-sql-injection-technical.html